# What is the fastest way to find a number $n$ based on modular properties of $n$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How do you find "intersection"s of moduli?

For example what is the fastest way to find a number $n$ based on modular properties of $n$?

Ex: Find is the first number $n$ such that:

1. $n \equiv 2 \mod 7$
2. $n \equiv 4 \mod 11$
3. $n \equiv 5 \mod 17$

(assumption is the modulus is prime)

This is very easy to do when they are all congruent to $0$, (hence it would just be $7*11*17$). I believe there should be a formula similar to this except using a couple constants involving the congruencies $2$, $4$, and $5$.

Comment: Look up "Chinese Remainder Theorem".

Comment: The [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) is applicable

Comment: Thanks for the refference, helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As was established in the comments, the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) says that this system of congruences has a solution because the moduli are pairwise coprime. Furthermore, any two solutions are congruent modulo $7\cdot 11\cdot 17$.

Several algorithms are described in the link, but I will use the [formula for the general case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#General_case):

$$x = \left[\sum_i a_i\frac{N}{n_i}\left[\left(\frac{N}{n_i}\right)^{-1}\right]_{n_i}\right]_N.$$

This looks scary, but it really isn't too difficult to work out once you substitute the numbers in. In this case we have

\begin{align*}
x &= \left[a_1\frac{N}{n_1}\left[\left(\frac{N}{n_1}\right)^{-1}\right]_{n_1} + a_2\frac{N}{n_2}\left[\left(\frac{N}{n_2}\right)^{-1}\right]_{n_2} + a_3\frac{N}{n_3}\left[\left(\frac{N}{n_3}\right)^{-1}\right]_{n_3}\right]_N\\
&= \left[2\frac{7\cdot 11\cdot 17}{7}\left[\left(\frac{7\cdot 11\cdot 17}{7}\right)^{-1}\right]_{7} + 4\frac{7\cdot 11\cdot 17}{11}\left[\left(\frac{7\cdot 11\cdot 17}{11}\right)^{-1}\right]_{11}\right.\\ 
&\ \ \ \ \ + \left.5\frac{7\cdot 11\cdot 17}{17}\left[\left(\frac{7\cdot 11\cdot 17}{17}\right)^{-1}\right]_{17}\right]_{7\cdot 11\cdot 17}\\
&= [374[187^{-1}]_7 + 476[119^{-1}]_{11} + 385[77^{-1}]_{17}]_{1309}\\
&= [374[5^{-1}]_7 + 476[9^{-1}]_{11} + 385[9^{-1}]_{17}]_{1309}\\
&= [374\times 3 + 476\times 5 + 385\times 2]\\
&= [4272]_{1309}\\
&= 345.
\end{align*}

Note that $345 \equiv 2 \bmod 7$, $345 \equiv 4 \bmod 11$, and $345 \equiv 5 \bmod 17$. By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, any other solution to the system of congruences is of the form $345 + 1309k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.